# CSS fixed column on table disappears on iPhone web browser

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a responsive CSS scrollable table with the first column fixed.

But on the iPhone web browser (Safari), the first column disappears. If you turn the iPhone on sideways/landscape, the fixed first column becomes visible. This was tested on iPhone X and 5.

On Android phones, this does not seem to be a problem.

Any idea what could be causing this problem on iPhone?

```css
div.page {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px -1px 11px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.95);
}

div.header {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background: #EBEBEB url('images/p5.png') repeat scroll;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

div.main {
  clear: both;
}

div.calc {
  width: 810px;
  float: left;
}

table.calc {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Calibri;
  width: 808px;
  border-bottom: medium silver solid;
}

#comparemob {
  display: none;
}

table.calc th[scope=col] {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

table.calc th[scope=row] {
  padding-left: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 332px;
}

table.calc th#gross {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(128, 128, 128, 1), rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5));
}

table.calc th#holiday {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255, 255, 0, 1), rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5));
}

table.calc th#empni {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(187, 86, 93, 1), rgba(187, 86, 93, 0.6));
}

table.calc th#umbfee {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(165, 129, 61, 1), rgba(165, 129, 61, 0.7));
}

table.calc th#expense {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255, 153, 0, 1), rgba(255, 153, 0, 0.7));
}

table.calc th#salary {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(153, 153, 153, 1), rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.7));
}

table.calc th#taxable {
  font-style: italic;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(166, 166, 166, 1), rgba(166, 166, 166, 0.7));
}

table.calc th#persallow {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(74, 174, 254, 1), rgba(74, 174, 254, 0.7));
}

table.calc th#married {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(128, 198, 254, 1), rgba(128, 198, 254, 0.7));
}

table.calc th#taxpaid {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1), rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

table.calc th#nicontri {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255, 51, 51, 1), rgba(255, 51, 51, 0.8));
}

table.calc th#tdeduct {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255, 77, 77, 1), rgba(255, 77, 77, 0.8));
}

table.calc th#takehome {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 204, 0, 1), rgba(0, 204, 0, 0.7));
}

table.calc td {
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

table.calc td:nth-child(odd) {
  background-image: url('images/Untitled-1.png');
}

table.calc tfoot th {
  padding-left: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #838383;
  color: white;
}

table.calc tfoot td {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  font-size: medium;
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
  color: #666666;
}

.row1 {
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
}

.row2 {
  background-color: #ffffa8;
}

.row3 {
  background-color: #f7b9bd;
}

.row4 {
  background-color: #dac399;
}

.row5 {
  background-color: #fbca81;
}

.row6 {
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
}

.row7 {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.row8 {
  background-color: #a8d8ff;
}

.row9 {
  background-color: #c7e6ff;
}

.row10 {
  background-color: #ffa3a3;
}

.row11 {
  background-color: #fdbfbe;
}

.row12 {
  background-color: #ffcaca;
}

.row13 {
  background-color: #A9F5A9;
}


/*table*/

table.rate {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

table.rate th,
tr,
td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

table.rate th {
  background-color: #60AFDB;
  border-bottom: 5px #0066CC solid;
}

table.rate td {
  background-color: #F6FDFF;
  border-bottom: 1px #60AFDB solid;
}

table.rate tbody {
  display: table-row-group;
  border-bottom: medium #60AFDB solid;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 740px) {
  body,
  div.data,
  .scroll/*, .main*/
  {
    width: 100%;
  }
  div.page {
    width: unset;
    margin: unset;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
  div.main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /*padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;*/
  }
  div.calc {
    width: 100%;
  }
  table.calc th[scope=col] {
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  .tabs {
    width: max-content;
    padding: 2px 5px 1px 2px;
  }
  .line {
    width: max-content;
  }
  .mscroll {
    /*width: 100%;*/
    overflow-x: scroll;
    margin-left: 105px;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
  .colfix,
  #compare,
  #blank {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
  }
  .colfix1 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    width: 85px;
    left: 20px;
    border-bottom: 2px black solid;
    border-top: 2px black solid;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
  }
  table.calc {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
  }
  table.calc th[scope=row] {
    font-size: 1.0em;
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta content="en-gb" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <title>table</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles10.css" type="text/css" />


  <style type="text/css">
    a {
      color: #0066CC;
    }
    
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script1.js">
    <!--
    //-->
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="page">

    <div class="main">
      <div class="calc">
        <div style="clear:left">
          <p>Test</p>
        </div>

        <div class="mscroll">
          <table class="calc">
            <tr style="border-bottom:2px black solid; border-top:2px black solid;">
              <th scope="col" style="border-bottom:2px black solid; border-top:2px black solid; height:22px; padding:0 0 -2px 5px; margin: -2px 0 -1px 3px;" id="blank">
                &nbsp;</th>
              <th class="slmrow" scope="col">1</th>
              <th class="slmrow" scope="col">2</th>
              <th class="slmrow" scope="col">3</th>
              <th class="slmrow" scope="col">4</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="gr" style="display:none;" class="row1">
              <th scope="row" id="gross" class="colfix" style="height: 43px">Name</th>
              <td style="height: 43px"></td>
              <td style="height: 43px"></td>
              <td style="height: 43px"></td>
              <td style="height: 43px"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="hf" style="display:none;" class="row2">
              <th scope="row" id="holiday" class="colfix">Name</th>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="emni" style="display:none;" class="row3">
              <th scope="row" id="empni" class="colfix">Name</th>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="umbf" style="display:none;" class="row4">
              <th scope="row" id="umbfee" class="colfix">Name</th>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row6">
              <th class="colfix" scope="row" id="salary" class="colfix">Name</th>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row8">
              <th scope="row" id="persallow" class="colfix">Name</th>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row10">
              <th scope="row" id="taxpaid" class="colfix">Name</th>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row11">
              <th scope="row" id="nicontri" class="colfix" style="height: 43px">
                Name</th>
              <td style="height: 43px"></td>
              <td style="height: 43px"></td>
              <td style="height: 43px"></td>
              <td style="height: 43px"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="hidetd" class="row12">
              <th scope="row" id="tdeduct" class="colfix">Name</th>
              <td><em>&nbsp;</em></td>
              <td><em></em></td>
              <td><em></em></td>
              <td><em></em></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row13">
              <th scope="row" id="take2" class="colfix">Name</th>
              <td><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
              <td><strong></strong></td>
              <td><strong></strong></td>
              <td><strong></strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tfoot>
              <tr id="hidecompare">
                <th class="slmrow" id="compare" style="height:19px;"><span id="comparedesktop">
            Name</span></th>
                <td><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
                <td><strong></strong></td>
                <td><strong></strong></td>
                <td><strong></strong></td>
              </tr>
            </tfoot>
          </table>
        </div>

      </div>


    </div>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Below you can see the first column missing on iPhone:

[image: iPhone screenshot of scrollable table]

Comment: How is the table scrollable? Vertically or horizontally? Its very short, how can you scroll it? And what do you mean, first column fixed? Via css or javascript?

Comment: To answer my question: You have horizontally scrollable table, where first column stays floating along left: 0;. And in iphone the entire column turns into a white block.

Comment: Yes that's correct. Do you know why this happens in iPhone web browser? I'm guessing it's something to do with the width of the first column!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started removing your code piece by piece to see when the problem goes away. Removing `<div class="mscroll">` made the problem go away. So I took closer look at the css and from there the problem seems to be in:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Remove that from **.mscroll** and it will work on iphone.

I did my best on trying to understand why this happens. But I don't seem to find any reason for it. I would assume, that your code is a bit messy and probably there is a conflict somewhere.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking in to this. I agree with you my codes a bit messy so there could be some conflict there. I did notice that Safari browsers does not seem to render webpages well compared to other browsers sometimes when there are some coding issues and sometimes codes have to be quite explicit for Safari